# GeoNetwork style customization

Tags: style, color, geonetwork

When I launch GeoNetwork, all changes in files of style (`geonetwork.css`, `gn_search_less`, `gn_view.less`,...) are lost, and the system generates a new file `/static/gn_search_default.css`.

How can I customize the GeoNetwork style (colors, style, ..) and have them persist every time I launch GeoNetwork?

Answer (score 1):

You changed the right files (.less files), but to see them visible you need to add debug parameter (?debug) or before launch delete all wro4j* files.

You add the debug parameter to the URL like:

`localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/slv/catalog.search?debug#/home`

This is what it looks like in a browser:

[image: debug param use with GeoNetwork URL]

Comment: how i can please add debug parameter? when I delete the wro4j* files , geonetwork don't work for me ( I see just in white interface)

Comment: Add it in url for example: http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/slv/catalog.search?debug#/home

And how it looks in browser: http://i.imgur.com/R03ywOw.png

Comment: After removing the wro4j files, you have to restart GeoNetwork.

Now, instead of removing the wro4j files, there is a "Clear JS/CSS cache" on the settings.